# Xamarin HttpClient Stack detection in runtime

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, httpclient

In Xamarin iOS application I'm able to specify which HttpClient implementation to use in runtime:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/http-stack/

However this setting only affects HttpClients constructed using default ctor:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
```

But what if I want to add some request interception to my http client by supplying custom DelegatingHandler to the ctor? I will then use another ctor:

```
var myDel = new MyDel(RUNTIME_HANDLER_GOES_HERE);
var client = new HttpClient(myDel);
```

Ideally in runtime I need to know which httpHandler is selected in compile time project settings in order to myDel to wrap it in runtime. How do I do it?

**UPD**
I was able to find the code responsible for selecting appropriate handler in mono's source: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/HttpClientEx.cs#L28 however RuntimeOptions class is internal and I can only use it via reflection in runtime. In this case however Xamarin's linker strips RuntimeOptions from dll in release mode and the app crashes in release and adhoc builds but not in debug. Does anyone know what happens to RuntimeOptions in linker-enabled xamarin build so I'm able to utilise it to find out runtime httphandler?

Comment: If at all possible I would sign up for a free trial on Xamarin University and there is a course over this very topic which might be a big help.  Its course XAM150 REST Web Services and it explains things alot better than I.  From what I remember from that course you can set the httpClienthandlers in code vs using the project settings and swap between CFNetworkHandler and NSUrlSessionHander as needed based upon your DelegatingHandlers you want to use.  Since you are doing this in code you know at run time which HTTPClientHandler you are installing to your HttpClient.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 Yeah, it now seems to me that you're correct. I can of cource control what handlers to pass into my DelegatingHandler as innerHandler, I was just wondering if there is an ability to determine which handler is selected as default in Xamarin's project settings to try to make it consistent across entire solution and for example inject that selected handler via Autofac or whatever into my service's HttpClient.

Comment: I see on that note I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fight the linker - it's removing it because it's a size optimization to be able to just use the required handler(s).

However you can still use reflection elsewhere, a place that the linker can't remove. You can see such an example in our [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/HttpClient/NetHttp.cs#L24). Here's the important line:

```
typeof(HttpMessageInvoker).GetField("_handler", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue (client).GetType ();
```

Comment: Well frankly speaking reflection is not safe too when you're using linker, as linker does not know if you're gona use certain private/public api in compile time because member names are hardcoded. However your answer suits best of all. When I don't know how the internals of HttpClient is constructed under the hood I can instantinate HttpClient and reflect (and in this case nothing is stripped by linker because I actually use HttpClient in my code) it in order to get internal handler. Not clean but works, yes.

Comment: The handler is sadly not exposed (e.g. as a property) by the public API. However reflection *can be* safe from the linker, you only need to make sure the information can't be removed (by your code or the code you call). In this case `handler` can't be removed if you're using `HttpClient`. Of course it's not *more* safe than reflection itself as it base itself on internals that could change over time (but that's unrelated to the linker itself).